# CloudSQL failed to login with root due to caching_sha2_password

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I've a CloudSQL private instance I access using CloudSQL Auth Proxy running in a container hosted to a bastion host and listening from 127.0.0.1. The RDBMS is MySql 8. The instance was provisioned by Terraform.

I usually connect to this using another container with mysql client this way:

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone "<bastion zone>" "<bastion name>" --project "<project id>" --tunnel-through-iap --command "sudo docker run --rm --network=host -it mysql mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1"
```

But when trying to login as 'root' i've this error: *Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' reported error: Authentication requires secure connection.*

This was totally unexpected because CloudSQL has legacy athentication enabled. In facts, logging with another user created by Terraform (yes, this happens only with root):

```
mysql> select user,host,plugin from user;
+-------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| user              | host      | plugin                |
+-------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| <the other user>  |           | mysql_native_password |
| root              | 127.0.0.1 | mysql_native_password |
| root              | ::1       | mysql_native_password |
| root              | localhost | mysql_native_password |
+-------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

exactly as it should look.

I also added this flag to the instance terraform setup:

```
database_flags {
  name  = "default_authentication_plugin"
  value = "mysql_native_password"
}
```

and reboot (replacing the instance is unfortunately not an option). No way: when trying to login as root, a sha2 connection is requested although it shouldn't.

i'm totally puzzled, this is a very unexpected behaviour. Any idea?

Comment: even more weird, after having updated to a newer minor version, now I get an Access denied on 'root', but ofc I didn't changed the password

Comment: `Access denie on root` does not mean an incorrect password. MySQL GRANT rules also determine WHO can log in from WHERE.

Comment: tnx allot @JohnHanley! My mind blowed so much that I didn't realized that! Thus, with _gcloud sql users set-password root --host=%_ command i was able to reset the behaviour as intended. I finally can login with the root user but...it has lost all the grants!

Comment: Post an answer with the command that solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Although this didn't explain why a sha2 authentication was required with a legacy user, this is how I was able to login with the root user.

The point is that with MYSQL8 the behaviour of the root user was changed and Google disincourage to use it.

Btw, as @John suggested in the comment, I had to grant the root user to login from *outside localhost*. This is the command I used:

```
gcloud sql users set-password root --host=% --prompt-for-password --instance=<cloudsql instance name> --project=<project id>
```

(Indeed I used it to also refresh the password at the same time)

But, as said before, the root behaviour is changed and that user have actually no grants, making him useless.

**Nonetheless the above command could be used to change the password for any user** (assuming the caller has enough permissions to do that).